# Shell sort multiple gaps

Tags: c++, shellsort

I have to create Shell sort code with gaps O(N^3/2) and O(N^4/3) with out reducing it to 1, how program does it now . This is what I've actually got:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int N;
  cout << "Amount of numbers: ";
  cin >> N;
  int d[N],h,i,j,x;
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) d[i] = rand() % 100;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) cout << setw(4) << d[i];
  cout << endl;
  for(h = 1; h < N; h =  2^h - 1 );
  //h = N/2;
  //if(!h) h++; 
  while(h)
  {
    for(j = N - h - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      x = d[j];
      i = j + h;
      while((i < N) && (x > d[i]))
      {
        d[i - h] = d[i];
        i += h;
      }
      d[i - h] = x;
    }
    h /= 3;
  }
  cout << "After sort :\n\n";
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) cout << setw(4) << d[i];
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Which part of the code were you asking us to write for you?

Comment: My program after sort shows numbers with gap 1 and wants to show with gap 3/2 and 4/3

Comment: The `^` operator performs bitwise-exclusive-or (XOR) not exponentiation so the expression `2^h` is not what you want.